# How can I trap the keyup event on the first item in a ListBox?

Tags: .net, wpf, event-handling, listbox

I have a ListBox with a TextBox above it.  I would like to use the arrow keys to navigate from the ListBox to the TextBox.

The intention is that if the first item in the ListBox is selected, and the user keys up, the TextBox will get focus.

I nearly have this working, but the problem is that when the user keys up, the SelectedItem is changed *before* the KeyUp event is raised.  This means that the navigation to the TextBox happens when the user has selected the *second* item in the ListBox.

How can I trap the keyup event on the first item in a ListBox?

```
<StackPanel>
 <TextBox Name="TextBox1"></TextBox>
 <ListBox Name="ListBox1" KeyUp="ListBox_KeyUp">
  <ListBoxItem>a</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>b</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>c</ListBoxItem>
 </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

```
    private void ListBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Up)
        {
            if (this.ListBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
                this.TextBox1.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you thought of listening for KeyDown instead?

Comment: @Lazarus: KeyDown is not raised :)

Comment: @Greg Sansom: That's odd then, perhaps you aren't seeing KeyDown at the ListBox but it may be at the ListBoxItem level? PreviewKeyDown or PreviewKeyUp seem to offer interesting possibilities too.

Comment: @Lazarus: KeyDown is not raised for the ListBoxItem either.  KeyUp *is* raised, but it's sender is the item which is being selected - so it has the same problem as in the question. The Preview events have the same issue.

Comment: @Greg Sansom: Why would you move away from the common convention of using the Tab to move from field to field?  I could be wrong, but most people who move from field to field with the keyboard are probably used to using Tab, and those who are not used to it, are probably moving field to field with a mouse or pointing device.

Comment: @Jesse: In the real product this is actually a custom built DropDownList, so it makes perfect sense for the up button to move to the TextBox - as far as the user is concerned, the TextBox and the ListBox are parts of the same control.

Comment: @Lazarus: Actually `KeyDown` *is* raised for the ListBoxItem, but it is also raised after SelectionChanged.

Comment: @Greg: That makes more sense!! Wish I could help, good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you really want to to this, you can use `PreviewKeyDown` as follows:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="textBox1"/>
        <ListBox PreviewKeyDown="ListBox_PreviewKeyDown">
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item1" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item2"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item3"/>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

with this code-behind:

```
    private void ListBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ListBox)
        {
            var listBox = sender as ListBox;
            if (listBox.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                if (e.Key == Key.Up && listBox.Items.Count > 0 && listBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    textBox1.Focus();
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to run the program?  Doing so would show you that it doesn't have that problem.  By using Preview we process the event **before** the ListBox.