# PreviewKeyDown for Windows Store App ListBox

Tags: c#, windows-8, listbox, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Is there an equivalent to the `PreviewKeyDown` for a **Windows Store App**? It isn't available.

I have exactly the same problem as [described here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686625/how-can-i-trap-the-keyup-event-on-the-first-item-in-a-listbox)

> I have a ListBox with a TextBox above it. I would like to use the arrow keys to navigate from the ListBox to the TextBox. The intention is that if the first item in the ListBox is selected, and the user keys up, the TextBox will get focus.

Comment: It should be noted that this isn't a duplicate question, since the linked problem above is for WPF.

Comment: The WPF question has the same problem, key scope!

Comment: It's polite to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah, tricky. Handling key events isn't super-obvious. Here's what you want:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += (s, args) =>
    {
        if ((args.EventType == CoreAcceleratorKeyEventType.SystemKeyDown 
            || args.EventType == CoreAcceleratorKeyEventType.KeyDown)
            && (args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Up))
        {
            MoveUp();
        }
        else if ((args.EventType == CoreAcceleratorKeyEventType.SystemKeyDown 
            || args.EventType == CoreAcceleratorKeyEventType.KeyDown)
            && (args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Down))
        {
            MoveDown();
        }
    };
}

private void MoveUp()
{
    // this part is up to you
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void MoveDown()
{
    // this part is up to you
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: This is really nice. But the AcceleratorKeyActivated event is triggered everytime a key is pressed, no matter which control is in focus. How do I check if the list is in focus? I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248486/check-if-listview-has-focus