# Detect Arrow Keys inside the window UWP

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, keyboard

I'm making an app with the UWP and I need a way to detect the arrow keys.

I know that exist other methods like using " Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived", but this one do'nt detect arrow keys. Some help pls?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16996731/17034

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PreviewKeyDown for Windows Store App ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651616/previewkeydown-for-windows-store-app-listbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends on the view and the UI controls that it contains.

Basically, a [UI Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.aspx) has the [KeyDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.keydown.aspx) and [KeyUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.keyup.aspx) events to which you can subscribe and control the key that was pressed/released on the keyboard.

You need to keep track of the focused object on the view as depending on which one has it, the event handler may not be called:

> By default, the first focusable element in the visual tree is given
>   focus by the system. An individual control gains focus when the user
>   clicks or taps directly on that control in the layout, or uses the Tab
>   key to step into a tab sequence within the content area. You can also
>   focus controls programmatically by calling Control.Focus.

So for example register to the Window's KeyDown event:

**Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication25.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
</Window>
```

**CS**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // ... Test for F5 key.
        if (e.Key == Key.F5)
        {
        this.Title = "You pressed F5";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It sais "The name Key does not exist in the current context" so I used Virtualkey, but just detect the key if I'm focusing a textbox.